# Subbing in parameter values

Tags: replacement

I have the following code

```
enteeigenexpf = eigenexp /. {mu -> 0.01, bet -> 0.001, d -> 0.1, m -> 0.3, 
alph -> 0.4, fc1 -> (c1/(c1 + 8)), fc2 -> ((c1 + inc)/(c1 + inc + 8))};

g[c1_, inc_] = eigenexpf;

eigenequilf = eigenequil /. {mu -> 0.01, bet -> 0.001, d -> 0.1, m -> 0.3, 
alph -> 0.4, fc1 -> (c1/(c1 + 8)),  fc2 -> ((c1 + inc)/(c1 + inc + 8))};

h[c1_, inc_] = eigenequilf;
```

eigenexp and eigenequil are some very large mathematica outputs. Since I am subbing in the same parameter values into both these functions I would prefer to have these values only in one line of code, so I don't have to edit both lines when I change things around. Suggestions?

Comment: `{enteeigenexpf, eigenequilf} = {eigenexp, eigenequil} /. {mu -> 0.01, bet -> 0.001, d -> 0.1, m -> 0.3, 
alph -> 0.4, fc1 -> (c1/(c1 + 8)),  fc2 -> ((c1 + inc)/(c1 + inc + 8))};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Mathematica* everything is an expression.

```
subs = {mu -> 0.01, bet -> 0.001, d -> 0.1, m -> 0.3, alph -> 0.4, fc1 -> (c1/(c1 + 8)), fc2 -> ((c1 + inc)/(c1 + inc + 8))};

enteeigenexpf = eigenexp /. subs;
```

etc.

Comment: Lovely! Thank you:)